# Excel Macros run but don't show in Developer Tab

Tags: excel

I created a spreadsheet in the past which contained buttons that would run macros in the workbook.  When I open the spreadsheet now and press the button, the macro will run perfectly.  However, on the Developer tab, there are no macros listed and no code available.  Is there a way to make the macros visible?

Comment: Have you checked the “PERSONAL.XLSB” book as well? It’s hidden by default but can be found in the Visual Basic editor

Comment: PERSONAL.XLSB does not exist, because I didn't realize that I needed to create the file.

Comment: PARTIAL RESOLUTION:  I was able to see the hidden code by opening the Visual Basic Editor and select my form.  On my form, I have a button when clicked, it calls the macros.  When I clicked the button, the VBA code for the macros appeared.  However, when I click the Macros button, it none of my macros show up.  At least I can copy my code to reuse in another workbook.

Comment: Could you paste one of the smaller functions that shows up in the editor but not the macro list? I'm assuming theyre either listed as 'functions' or 'private' so they aren't showing up

Comment: Christian's also made a good point that functions that require parameters could also be hidden

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand. Is that your problem?

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

' This Macro is shown.
Public Sub X()
   MsgBox ("X")
End Sub

' This Macro is hidden.
Public Sub Y(ByVal N As Long)
   MsgBox ("Y")
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you meant to say "Private" for the second sub?

Comment: No. I meant the argument "ByVal N As Long" in Sub Y(). With my Excel 2010 Sub Y() is not shown in the list of subroutines of "Developer...". I do not know the exact Menu. Here in Germany it is called "Entwicklertools/Makros". Y() ist not listed.